# Generalizing a method with different internal method calls

Tags: java

I have two methods that create a `Map` from a `List` of objects:

```
private Map<String, Foo> getFooMap(List<Foo> oos) {
    return foos.stream()
            .map(foo -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(foo.getText(), foo))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey,
                    AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue));
}

private Map<String, Bar> getBarMap(List<Bar> bars) {
    return bars.stream()
            .map(bar -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(bar.getName(), bar))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey,
                    AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue));
}
```

I want to create a more generalized function because they're mostly identical. The only difference (other than the object type) is the method the creates the key: `foo.getText()` vs `bar.getName()`. Is there a good way to turn these into a single method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just pass a `Function` to extract the key. Also, you don't need the `Entry` in between:

```
static <T, K> Map<K, T> toMap(List<T> list, Function<? super T, K> getKey) {
    return list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(getKey, Function.identity()));
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
Map<String, Foo> fooMap = toMap(foos, Foo::getText);
Map<String, Bar> barMap = toMap(bars, Bar::getName);
```

Answer (score 0):

See the comments, below.

```
// Alternate to "AbstractMap.SimpleEntry".  This may seem redundant,
// but one rather should avoid coupling one's implementation to other
// implementations.

public class SimpleEntry<K, V> implements Map.Entry<K, V> {
    public SimpleEntry(K k, V v) {
        this.k = k;
        this.v = v;
    }

    private K k;
    public K getKey() { return k; }

    private V v;
    @Override
    public V getValue() { return v; }
    @Override
    public V setValue(V v) { V oldV = this.v; this.v = v; return oldV; }
}

// A representative element class.

public static class Foo {
    public String getText() {
        return "text";
    }
}

// The mapping example, changed to use simple entry, and to use "Map.Entry" based functions
// as the parameters to Collectors.toMap.  Map.Entry is a public interface; AbstractMap.SimpleEntry
// is an implementation type.  Note that since AbstractMap.SimpleEntry implements Map.Entry, this
// still works.

public Map<String, Foo> getFooMap(List<Foo> foos) {
    return foos.stream()
            .map( foo -> new SimpleEntry<String, Foo>(foo.getText(), foo) )
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}

// An attempt to generalize the element and key types.  This fails because 'foo.getText()'
// is no longer understood.

public <K, V> Map<K, V> getMap1(List<V> foos) {
    return foos.stream()
            .map( foo -> new SimpleEntry<K, V>(foo.getText(), foo) )
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}

// Second attempt: The prior 'foo.getText()' is replaced with function 'keyGetter',
// which is a new parameter to the method.

public <K, V> Map<K, V> getMap2(List<V> foos, Function<V, K> keyGetter) {
    return foos.stream()
            .map( foo -> new SimpleEntry<K, V>(keyGetter.apply(foo), foo) )
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```